# Posting large files using azure data factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am looking for some advices. I need to read a large file (>500MB) from the blob storage (it is encrypted at rest) with keys from the key vault. And then I need to push the file (it is a zip) as it is to a REST service with the file as body using form-data.

I tried to use a web request but apparently the payload is limited to 1.5 MB.

Any advice?

Comment: The payload size limit should be determined by the REST API's server, so unlikely there is anyway around that. Even if you could, I think trying to send a file that large as a payload would be fraught with issues. Timeouts, latency, checksum failures, etc. I know that's not very helpful, but I would definitely be looking for a different solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the feedback, I understand that intuitively using REST to upload large binary payloads does not make sense but my understanding is that to upload large files to the blob storage, the azure client relies on http (indeed http != rest). Am I missing something?

Comment: HTTP(S) is the protocol, but the upload is almost certainly done in chunks/blocks rather than as a single payload. AzCopy, Storage Explorer, the SDK, they all operate that way. When you add the data to the REST payload, won't it try to include the entire binary value as a single property?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, actually what I am referring to is a REST service with a rest payload with a multipart. But I can split it and do a upload with a multipart first. What would be the best way then to push a file using a multipart. My server is Apache Oak : https://jackrabbit.apache.org/oak/